# placeholder does not appear in input

Tags: html, forms, input, placeholder

I have a problem - placeholder does not appear in input in my html document.
Here is the code:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color:#fff;
 opacity:1;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
 color:#fff;
 opacity:1;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
 color:#fff;
 opacity:1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
 color:#fff;
 opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="input">
     <input placeholder="Ваше имя" type="text" name="name" value="<?= $name ?>" tabindex="1" autofocus>
     <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: My first guess would be that `$name` is not empty then …? If that’s not it, then you need to show us a proper [mcve]. (That could be just the resulting HTML code in this case, but your PHP code is not really helpful here, because we don’t know what values your variables have.)

Comment: if you have a set value, a placeholder won't show, only on add-type forms should a placeholder exist

Answer (score 2):

First, your placeholder is replaced by the `value=""`, also your placeholder color is set to `#fff`

```html
<fieldset class="input">
    <input placeholder="Hello World!" type="text" name="name" tabindex="1">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I also have a field 
<textarea placeholder = "Your message" value = "<? = $ message?>" name = "message" tabindex = "3"> </ textarea>
 and here placeholder is displayed.